# Linear Constraints Solution Existence

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, linear-programming

how can one decide if

$$A*t\ge b$$

$A$ is a Matrix with integer Entries and $t$ is a Vector with integer Entries, $b$ is a fixed Vector with integer Entries

exists?

Comment: Do you mean how can one decide whether a solution $t$ to the inequality exists for a given matrix $A$?

Comment: yes exactly !!!

Comment: You can always take $t$ to be the zero vector. So what is the non-trivial version of your question?

Comment: non-trivial version of the question is when 0 is b, with b an integer vector. I will edit it sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This is known as integer linear programming, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming . The only difference is that you aren't maximizing a linear functional, you just want a feasible solution to your inequalities. You can get a solution (or determine that none exists) by solving $At \geq b - \epsilon$ where you maximize $\epsilon$ and if you get a solution $t,\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \geq 0$ then you have found a solution to your inequalities $At \geq b$. Integer linear programming is NP-hard, so there are probably no fast algorithms for it; however there are solvers like Cplex that use branch-and-bound and other techniques that can sometimes get a solution quickly.